# How to create a block template in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have created a block using quicktab module.

1. block_name = league_websites_overview_promo_t
2. in drupal 6 template was = league_websites_overview_promo_t.tpl.php
3. I have upgraded my website from D6 to D7

but league_websites_overview_promo_t template not loading in drupal 7.

What should be the template name in D7?

Comment: Have you checked the [Drupal Template Suggestions page](https://drupal.org/node/1089656)?

Answer (score 2):

[Refrence](http://drupal.org/node/1089656):

Should be: `league-websites-overview-promo-t.tpl.php` (Underscore _ will be get replace by dash-)